# Can internal organs be splinched?

Tags: harry-potter

We see that when people fail their apparition tests, there's a bit of splinching that happens.  It can be funny (an eyebrow was left behind) to horrific and gory (Ron leaving a bit of himself behind in Deathly Hallows).  My question is, can internal organs be left behind (like a bit of kidney or even brain).

Comment: "*‘They left half of themselves behind,’ said Mr Weasley, now spooning large amounts of treacle onto his porridge. ‘So, of course, they were stuck. Couldn’t move either way. Had to wait for the Accidental Magic Reversal Squad to sort them out. Meant a fair old bit of paperwork, I can tell you, what with the Muggles who spotted the body parts they’d left behind …’
Harry had a sudden vision of a pair of legs and an eyeball lying abandoned on the pavement of Privet Drive.*"

Comment: http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Splinching

Comment: Those are still external, I meant more like a part of internal organs.

Comment: I'm just looking now. As far as I can tell, the answer is "dunno".

Comment: you appears to loose whole pieces of your body, chunks if you will, from exterior in to a set point, we dont have any indication that you can only leave behind something interior

Comment: An eyeball is pretty close to internal.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I'd argue that Harry is hardly equipped to teach us about splinching, having only heard about it a few seconds earlier. And the teacher is most likely having a bit of fun with his young students.

Comment: @Valorum t̶e̶a̶c̶h̶e̶r̶ rons dad, though to point out technically we dont know if anyone lost and eye, thats just what harry envisioned.

Comment: @Himarm: good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Half Blood Prince*, Susan Bones is splinched during one of their lessons in the Great Hall. She leaves her entire leg behind. Therefore roughly a quarter or fifth of the body was removed and left standing there. A great, thick width of flesh, bone and skin was sliced through for this to happen.

Surely this, combined with the aforementioned quote about leaving half of themselves behind (@Valorum), and the grave warnings that come with Apparition lessons, is pretty strong evidence that internal organs are surely within considerable risk during Apparition. Some of them are far nearer to the skin than slicing a leg off. Few are protected by as much bone as would be broken to remove a leg. I don't see any reason that they should be protected - apart from the author not wanting to be too gross!

Comment: i almost think he wants to know if you can loose your kidney, without having a gaping hole in your side, while the splinching accidents WE see are always chunks of the body from the skin in.

Comment: Well if you can leave an eyebrow just hanging there... Why not?

Comment: Wait... does that mean that someone might accidentally splinch their heart, or their brain, or their entire head and just die instantly? It seems to me that if I'm going to be attempting something that could instantly kill me if I did it wrong, I'd want more advice than just "destination, determination and deliberation".

Comment: @Dr R Dizzle - Well, it's just an analogy for driving isn't it? Loads of people do it, you require a license and it's probably the most risky thing you do each and every day. It is commonplace, but there are strict rules about it.